# What is the most appropriate sizing measure for mobile websites / hybrid apps?

Tags: responsive-design, viewport-units

I am used to use **px** on desktop and sometime **em** (even though I don't know why one is best when developing a responsive interface).

My concern now is: shall I use **px**, **viewport units** (vh,vw) or what else when developing for mobile?

Comment: px is absolute, viewport units are relative. Do you catch the different uses with different displays sizes?

Comment: looks like viewports are "responsive". pixel are not. however I'm not sure about the best practice, especially for what concerns horizontal units

Comment: you can(must) use both. Even with a responsive application/website, some stuff are *always* the same size (ie: Logo, Footer...)

Comment: thank you @Thomas . what about alignment?

Comment: I'm far from an expert in CSS unfortunately... You'll find a lot more answers on the [CSS chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-web-development) of SO